# iOS Know When Section Header is Scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am working on an iPhone app where I would like some custom behavior to be performed when the section header gets pushed out of the way by the next one. Is there any way I can tell when this is happening in `scrollViewDidScroll`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rectForHeaderInSection` to get any section's actual position:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView_ {
    ...
    CGRect rect = [mytable convertRect:[mytable rectForHeaderInSection:0] toView:[mytable superview]];
    ...
}
```

To achieve what you mentioned in the `scrollViewDidScroll` you might loop through all section (as you defined in your table) and check `rect.origin.y` to get whether it is negative value (outside of visible area) or not.

Hope it helps as starting thought for detailed implementation! [Check reference also.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/rectForHeaderInSection%3a)

Answer (score 0):

In case you target iOS 6 and later you can use `tableView:didEndDisplayingHeaderView:forSection:` method from `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // do what you need
}
```